# Show that in general $A \cup (B \times C) \neq (A \cup B) \times (A \cup C)$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have been reading the real analysis textbook "Modern Real Analysis" by William Ziemer.
I have come to an exercise that seemed strange to me. I was able to answer it I believe, but it seemed to me that there may be an error in the book here.

The question is :

> Show that $A \times (B \cup C) = (A \times B) \cup (A \times C)$.
> Also, show that in general, $A \cup (B \times C) \neq (A \cup B) \times (A \cup C)$.

I was able to do the first part easily, but I was confused by the second. It seems easy to construct an example where the equality doesn't hold. For instance :
\begin{align}
A & = \{0,1\}\\
B & = \{2,3\}\\
C & = \{4,5\}
\end{align}
So :
\begin{align}
A \cup (B \times C) 
  & = \{0,1\} \cup \{ (2,4) , (2,5) , (3,4) , (3,5) \}\\
  & = \{0,1,(2,4),(2,5),(3,4),(3,5) \}
\end{align}
and :
\begin{align}
A \cup B & = \{0,1,2,3\}\\
A \cup C & = \{0,1,4,5\}
\end{align}
So :
\begin{equation}
0 \not \in (A \cup B) \times (A \cup C)
\end{equation}
and therefore :
\begin{equation}
A \cup (B \times C) \neq (A \cup B) \times (A \cup C) \; \checkmark
\end{equation}
But this second part of the problem seems strange. Is this a likely error in the book, or is there something that I am not seeing ?

Comment: Use $\cup$ (\cup) rather than$\bigcup$ (\bigcup) for the binary intersection operator. $\bigcup$ is for forming the union of a family of sets. I have fixed this for you.

Comment: dear scipio, why do you think this is an error? the exercise shows that $\times$ distributes over $\cup$, but that $\cup$ does not in general distribute over $\times$, so the two parts of the problem are certainly connected

Comment: This is rather like in arithmetic where $a(b + c) = ab + ac$ for any $a, b$ and $c$, while $a + bc \neq (a + b)(a +c)$ except for a few special values of $a, b$ and $c$.

Comment: The second equality can only hold if $A=\emptyset$, in which case it is trivial. Otherwise the RHS is a set containing only pairs of elements from $A,B,C$, while the LHS also contains single elements of $A$.

Comment: Atticus -- I guess I just thought it was an error because the second equality is obviously not true.  But you seem to be right that they are just showing that one operator distributes over the other but not vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

There's something you're not seeing.  Assume $A$ has three elements and $B$ and $C$ each have two elements, all of which are distinct.  Then $A \cup (B \times C)$ has $7$ elements, which is prime, whereas $(A \cup B) \times (A \cup C)$ has $25$ elements.

Answer (score 0):

It's not even close. $A\cup(B×C)$ contains unpaired elements of $A$ and ordered pairs of elements from $B$ and $C$, whereas $(A\cup B)×(A\cup C)$ contains only ordered pairs including those where elements of $A$ are repeated.

Comment: OP is not asking why this statement is not true, they have already demonstrated that in the question body. Rather they are wondering why it's relevant at all, and how it's connected to the true statement they were asked to prove. While it's true that the question in title is different from the actual question, upon reading the whole post it should become clear that OP is not asking for a proof of the statement in the title.